# can't get mixpanel with angulartics to work

Tags: angularjs, mixpanel, angulartics

I'm testing out the example angulartics code for mixpanel on my mixpanel account and all requests to the mixpanel `track` api are cancelled and show in red in Chrome network tab.

My test:
http://chovy.us.to/angulartics/samples/mixpanel.html#/c

github:
http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/

Example: https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics/blob/master/samples/mixpanel.html

Comment: any progress ? i have the same problem ;-) !

Comment: nope. i gave up and went with GA.

Comment: Nope, I was using ghostery. I think it finally worked, but I had to completely remove the Ghostery extension, disabling it even in chrome didn't help. Took forever, and I had already moved on.